# How can I export multiple files while compiling less to css from gulp?

Tags: css, gulp, less

Right now, I am using Gulp for a project which is basically a CSS framework. The way I am doing it right now is, I @import all the other .less files in a single app.less and then pass it to the Gulp task:

```
// Compile
gulp.task("compile", function() {
    return gulp
        .src("source/app.less")
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(concat("framework.edge.css"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist"))
        .pipe(
            autoprefixer({
                browsers: ["last 4 versions"],
                cascade: false
            })
        )
        .pipe(concat("framework.css"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist"))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(
            uglify({
                maxLineLength: 80,
                UglyComments: false
            })
        )
        .pipe(concat("framework.min.css"))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write("./"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist"));
});
```

This works totally as expected. The stylesheets are first compiled and the exported as `app.edge.css`, then it is passed through autoprefixer, exporting `framework.css` and then the minification process.

The problem is, now I want to export each stylesheet as a separate module, such as

- grids.css
- scaffolding.css
- and so on...

How can I achieve this? I am actually not getting what logic to apply.

Comment: Can't you simply remove the @imports and change your gulp.src to include them all and remove all the concat pipes? The concats will combine them into one file - you don't want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use globbing**

If a `gulp` tasks's `src` is `x/**/*.less`, the task will process all LESS files in `x` or any subfolder of `x` and will output each file separately in the `dest`, preserving the `src`'s file structure.

To exclude a file or files, use `!...`.

Learn the globbing rules in the [Glob Primer](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#glob-primer), and test your pattern with the [Glob online tester](https://codepen.io/mrmlnc/pen/OXQjrZ)

Depending on your needs, you might want two tasks, one for outputting individual files and one for building the full `framework.css`.